# Extract 2 numbers preceded by two different strings from paragraph using Tcl Regular Expression

Tags: tcl

I need to extract two different numbers preceded by two different strings.
`Employee Id--> Employee16`(I need 16) and
`Employee links--> Employee links:2` (I need 2).
Source String looks like following:

```
Employee16, Employee name is QueenRose
  Working for 46w0d
  Billing is Distributed
  65537 assigned tasks, 0 reordered, 0 unassigned
  0 discarded, 0 lost received, 5/255 load
  received sequence unavailable, 0xC2E7 sent sequence
  Employee links: 2 active, 0 inactive (max not set, min not set)
    Dt3/5/10:0, since 46w0d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:10, since 21w0d, no tasks rcvd
 Employee is currently working in Hardware section.

Employee19, Employee name is Edward11
  Working  for 48w4d
  Billing is Distributed
  206801498 assigned tasks, 0 reordered, 0 unassigned
  655372 discarded, 0 lost received, 9/255 load
  received sequence unavailable, 0x23CA sent sequence
  Employee links: 7 active, 0 inactive (max not set, min not set)
    Dt3/5/10:0, since 47w2d, tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:10, since 28w6d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:11, since 18w4d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:12, since 18w4d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:13, since 18w4d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:14, since 18w4d, no tasks pending
    Dt3/5/10:15, since 7w2d, no tasks pending
   Employee is currently working in Hardware sectione.

Employee6 (inactive)
  Employee links: 2
    Dt3/5/10:0 (inactive)
    Dt3/5/10:10 (inactive)

Employee7 (inactive)
  Employee links: 2
    Dt3/5/10:0 (inactive)
    Dt3/5/10:10 (inactive)
```

Tried with the following:

```
Employee(\d+)[^\n\r]*[^M]*Employee links:\s+(\d+)
```

Expecting output to be like:

```
16  2
19  7
 6  2
 7  2
```

But is not listing all the Ids and links.
Can anybody help me getting this?

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to extract from the two different locations as two separate matching steps. It's also *by far* easiest if you split the whole text up into paragraphs first.

> `Employee Id--> Employee16` (I need 16)

I'd extract a single one like this:

```
regexp -line {^Employee(\d+),} $paragraph -> employeeNumber
```

(You want line matching mode for this task, rather than the default "whole string" matching mode.)

> `Employee links--> Employee links:2` (I need 2)

For this one, again already assuming that we're only looking at the overall record for a single employee:

```
regexp -line {^\s+Employee links:\s*(\d+)(.*)$} $paragraph -> links rest
```

In this case, I've extracted not just the `$links` but also the `$rest` of the line, since it seems that you might need to be able to think about whether that matters. Of course, it might be that the following is even more useful:

```
regexp -line {^\s+Employee links:\s*(\d+)(?:\s+active,\s+(\d+)\s+inactive)?} \
        $paragraph -> activeLinks inactiveLinks
```

In this case, the `$inactiveLinks` will have an empty string if only the first number was present (which seems to happen when the employee is inactive; you'll need to do a trivial bit of logic to tidy up in that case).

Finally, when using `regexp`, don't forget to check the result to see if it matched!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to provide a complete answer, but then I read Donal much more helpful tutorial and felt I just couldn't.  I will show how to split the text up into paragraphs though:

```
foreach paragraph [regexp -all -inline {.*?\n{2,}} $text] {
    do something with $paragraph
}
```

In your attempt, I see `[^\n\r]*` -- are you *sure* you have carriage returns in your text as well as newlines?